# Remaping rear jacks for 5.1 Speaker System

Tags: audio, manjaro

I am new to Linux and got recommended Manjaro. So far it's fine, but I ran into a problem with my 5.1 speaker setup. In Windows, I could use Realtek Manager to remap the jack i used for my Rear Speakers because there seems to be some weird issue I'm having where the correct jack for the Rear Speakers will only produce sound from my Rear Right speaker and no matter what, the Left Rear Speaker is mute. Now the problem isn't in the speaker since as I said I plugged the jack in the Line In jack next to my Front Speaker Jack and remapped it to be a Rear Speaker Jack and sound comes from both speakers. But in Manjaro there is no Realtek for me to easily do this, and the only solution i found was to use Jack retasking, but no matter what i do i can't seem to get it right. Id appreciates any help as it feels like I'm just banging my head against the wall.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like i needed to override my headphones front jack for everything to work. Also, i dont know why but when i save my override as Internal Speaker (back) and the rest as Line Out(Center/LE) and Line Out(Front) it works, so im not gona complain.